# Выделение соседних элементов списка по наведению курсора

Tags: меню, html, css, список

Всем привет. Помогите советом. Есть меню, реализованное с помощью списка (`ul`), элементы меню разделяются вертикальными слешами ("|"). Необходимо, чтобы при наведении на какой либо пункт меню (`CATEGORYn`) соседние разделители исчезали (сливались с фоном). [Вот](http://codepen.io/kupas/pen/fvcuy) как это выглядит.

Конструкцию в HTML можно менять.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

```
<nav>
<ul id = "navi_ul">
  <li><a href = "#">CATEGORY1</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">CATEGORY2</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">CATEGORY3</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">CATEGORY4</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">CATEGORY5</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">CATEGORY6</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

-

```
nav{
 height:30px; 
 background-color:#e2e1dd;}

#navi_ul{
 line-height:2.5; 
 list-style:none;
 font-size:12px;}

#navi_ul li{
    position:relative;
 float:left; 
 color:#9c9e9d;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#navi_ul li:before{
    position: absolute;
 content: "|";
}

#navi_ul li a{
 text-decoration:none; 
 color:#2b2b2b; 
 display:inline-block; 
 padding:0 14px 0 14px;}

#navi_ul li:hover a{
 background-color:#666; 
 color:#ff7700;}

#navi_ul li:hover:before{
  content: '';
}

#navi_ul li:hover +li:before{
  content: '';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3TC6L/1/ - и никаких скриптов!

Comment: ОЧЕНЬ спасибо вам) жаль что пока как новичек не могу еще ни вам ни предыдущему оратору репутацию повысить)

Comment: >жаль что пока как новичек не могу еще ни вам ни предыдущему оратору репутацию повысить)

@kupas - можете для этого поставте галку с правильным ответом :)

Comment: Я так понял, что поддержка IE6-7 не требуется? Если да, то и слава богу.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#navi_ul li').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).prev().css('color','#e2e1dd');
  $(this).next().css('color','#e2e1dd');
});
$('#navi_ul li').mouseout(function(){
  $(this).prev().css('color','#9c9e9d');
  $(this).next().css('color','#9c9e9d')
});
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, вы мне очень помогли)

Comment: Минусатор, за что минусуем-то? За то, что jQuery? Зато все коротко и ясно. Без лишних телодвижений, и js в современных браузерах исполняется достаточно быстро. Кроме того в вопросе не оговаривалось, какую технологию использовать.